# R Gibbs sampler error subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, sample

I am building a small gibbs sampler but R returns: "Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = NA_real_) : subscript out of bounds".

Problem is with this line:

```
mu[i,j] <- alpha[i]+beta[i]*(x[j]-mean(x[]))
```

I just do not understand why?

```
GS <- function(x){
    alpha <- c()
    beta <- c()
    mu <- matrix()
    Y <- matrix ()
    for (i in 1:x){
        alpha[i] <- rnorm(1,0)
        beta[i] <- rnorm(1,0)
        for (j in 1:5){
            mu[i,j] <- alpha[i]+beta[i]*(x[j]-mean(x[]))
            Y[i,j] <- rnorm(1, mu[i,j], 1)
        }
        Y
    }
}
```

Comment: Start removing part of the code to isolate where the error is.

Comment: I would suggest that you set `options(error=recover)`, to know what line of code is the problem. Then look at your variables, and you will probably figure out what is going on. Also there are many documents online explaining how to debug (see for example http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-debug-tools.pdf , or search here on SO)

Comment: @Jealie Thank you for your reply. Yes. I have found the problematic code, I just do not know why?

Comment: If you know how big `mu` will be, initialize it full-size: `mu = matrix(NA, nrow = length(x), ncol = 5)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you don't initialize your vectors or matrices so the vectors will have lenght 0 and the matrices will only consist of one NA. So you can't write anything to position i since it doesn't exist.

Change

```
    alpha <- c()
    beta <- c()
    mu <- matrix()
    Y <- matrix ()
```

to

```
    alpha <- numeric(x)
    beta <- numeric(x)
    mu <- matrix(0,x,5)
    Y <- matrix (0,x,5)
```

Comment: That's indeed the solution, but for the record, un-initialized matrices have size 1x1 and contain `NA`. Just type `matrix()` to verify :)

Comment: Hi, can you help me see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65054971/how-to-debug-for-my-gibbs-sampler-of-bayesian-regression-in-r? Thank you.